# How to merge List of two objects based on unique id?

Tags: collections, groovy

I have a class

```
class Topic {
    Integer id
    String name
    Integer numberPosts
}
```

and another one

```
class TopicDetails {
    Integer id
    Integer numberPosts
}
```

The second is actually a container for query results that's why the similarity.

I have two lists `List<Topic>` and `List<TopicDetails>`. Objects will be unique by id in both the lists. The second one will have at most all the ids as the first list.

I want to merge the data from second list to first list. I understand that there are simple ways like

- to iterate over both and check for ids and merge the details
- Using a map for the details.

But is there some better way to do this? `Collection` framework has many new methods so I was thinking that there may be some elegant way to do this in groovy instead of doing the above mentioned methods.

**EDIT** I forgot to mention that the first one initially does not have the information regarding the numberPosts. That is why the second one is present i.e. as a container for information from the database.

Comment: Are your lists sorted? If so, does `get(i)` really mean anything? What would the cost be of just switching to a map?

Comment: when you say "The second one will have at most all the ids as the first list" does that mean the 2nd doesn't have anything the first doesn't? So, can't you just ignore the second list?

Comment: @k_g No the lists are not sorted. I did not get what do you mean by `get(i)`. I can switch to a map in a particular case but I wanted to know specifically how such a scenario can be handled.

Comment: @AseemBansal I was using `get(i)` for the the list function that allows you to get an item at a specific location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A List is still just a list. You can use lambda expressions and "find" the ID each time, but you gain nothing in efficiency. A map is the way to go, at least for one of the lists.